# python parse string in date format to get the date

Tags: python

There is a string and a date format. I want to get the date based on format.

If date format is `YYYY.MM.dd` and string is `2017.01.01`. It should transform to a valid date object.

How can I find the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **datetime** module something like this :

```
from datetime import datetime
date_object = datetime.strptime('2017.01.01', '%Y.%m.%d') # Converting the given date string into a datetime object. 
formatted_date = date_object.strftime('%c') #User Defined Output Format
print(formatted_date)
```

This will result in :

```
Sun Jan  1 00:00:00 2017
```

You can refer to the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: But by format is `YYYY.MM.dd`. Can I use it without modifying it?

Comment: What do you mean by without modifying it?

Comment: Give `YYYY.MM.dd` as my argument instead of `%Y.%m.%d`

Comment: You may have to handle string conversions then. Why is that a necessity ?

Comment: yes, I get the string and format as input and have to have to use the date. Format is in java datetime specifications.